# Miniter runs, but the robot's motor does not work

Tags: rosbridge, arduino#ros#raspberry

I'm using ros2 humble

I tried to use the motor using Arduino, l298n, encoder motor using the miniterm,

I received an answer from the miniter that if I check the status, it will be okay (example o 255 255 -> ok),
It has been confirmed that the actual motor is not running.

I referred to the video below.[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PCuDnpgiew)

The connection line was also correctly connected.

[image]

[image]

I built by installing ros arduino bridge in my workspace src.

I'm already install pyserial

Is this a problem with the motor driver or is it a problem with the software?